# Path of linux home in spring mvc property file

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have deployed a java web application to the tomcat in Linux server. The application used to save and retrieve files like images, xls files etc. I have specified the path in the property file of java application. Unfortunately the application is not storing the files on the location which i have given in property files. Can someone help me to correct the property file ?

```
base_path=\\home\\TestAppUploads\\
sectionImagePath=SectionImages
questionImages=QuestionImages
answerDescrImages=AnswerDescrImages
optionImages=OptionImages
userImages=UserImages
announcementImages=AnnouncementImages
```

Comment: *"Its not working as I expected"* -  It is not a good problem statement. You need to provide details. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my first tought: have you tried the normal slash? 
Because linux uses different slashes in path.

For example: ***base_path***=/home/testinguser

I know this is a property file but if you want to handle this kind of problem inside your
Java code you might want to use ***File.separator***

But it would be helpfull if you could paste here the error log